# EF Database First - Update EDMX file without opening it?

Tags: ef-database-first

how can I update the .edmx file without opening the designer, if that's possible? The db has like so many tables and every time I need to update the .edmx from database, visual studio hangs for a good 10 minutes (or so)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution per se, but more of a workaround. If you have many tables like I do, (almost 300), move them to different diagrams. You can do this manually by editing the .edmx file and moving the tables that way, using the UI is too cumbersome.

This improved things dramatically for me.